# EF self reference table in mysql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want one self reference table using EF (version 6.0) in mysql (version 5.7.20).

MySQL table:

```
Create table Category
id int(11) Primary Key,
name varchar(50),
ParentId int(11) Default Null,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY`Parent_Key` (`ParentId`),
CONSTRAINT`Parent_Key` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentId`) REFERENCES`Category` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

EF CODE:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}

    public virtual Category Parent {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children {get; set;}
};
```

EF ModelConfiguration

```
CategoryConfiguration() 
{
  this.HasKey(e => new {e.id})
  this.Property(e => e.id) 
      .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity); 
  this.HasOptional(e => e.Parent) .WithMany(e => Children) .HasForeignKey(e => new {e.id, e.ParentId); }
```

this is the skeleton running code and it runs without error. the problem is when I get the Category by linq _db.Categories; the Parent property and Children list are always null, even I add include clause.

PS: the ParentId is the idCategory value if set a category to be a parent category.

Would anyone tell me what is wrong in my code and config? Or this is only can be get in SQLServer can't get work in MySQL.

Comment: Could you show your SQL you to retrieve parent and child ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you copy/pasted and changed the code so it is not your real app. There is something strange in your configuration (2 Keys).
Anyway, here there is a working example with MySQL

Context

```
class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(){}

    public Context(DbConnection connection) : base (connection, true){}

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.Parent).WithMany(e => e.Children).HasForeignKey(e => new {e.ParentId});
    }
}
```

Model (same as your but I've added the initialization of Children collection

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Children = new List<Category>();
    }

    public int Id {get; set;}

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description {get; set;}

    public int? ParentId {get; set;}

    public virtual Category Parent {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children {get; set;}
}
```

Test application (if you run more than 1 time you'll receive an exception because you'll have 6 children).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string connectionString = "Server=10.0.0.26;Database=EfTest;Uid=admin;Pwd=password";


    using (DbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (Context context = new Context(connection))
    {
        context.Categories.Add(new Category() { Description = "Root" });
        context.SaveChanges();

        Category rootCategory = context.Categories.First(_ => _.Description == "Root");
        rootCategory.Children.Add(new Category() { Description = "Child1" });
        rootCategory.Children.Add(new Category() { Description = "Child2" });
        rootCategory.Children.Add(new Category() { Description = "Child3" });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (DbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (Context context = new Context(connection))
    {
        Category rootCategory = context.Categories.First(_ => _.Description == "Root");
        Debug.Assert(rootCategory.Children.Count == 3);
    }


}
```